# sql: group by partial match

Tags: sql, oracle

```
+----+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | dur  | workdur                                | 
+----+------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | 64   | /home/public/users/james/PB_3594162_0  |   
| 2  | 123  | /home/public/users/john/PB_990-94162_0 |
| 3  | 13   | /doc/users/jason/PB_0125135            |
| 4  | 355  | /doc/users/jason/notPB                 |
```

I can get all PB_ ones with

```
select workdur from work where workdur like '%PB_%'
```

How can I group by partial string of `"%PB_"` so that i can get average `dur` of the above select?

NOTE: in the select statement, id=4 wont be selected

Comment: What type of DB is it?

Comment: oracle and why -1?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.  Also tag the question with the database you are using.  I mean, doesn't `select avg(dur) . . .` do what you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no because that will include the 4th one which doesnt start with PB_

Comment: @ealeon Because there are other kind of databases besides oracle.

Comment: @ealeon . . . But your question explicitly says "get average `dur` of the above select", so that would include all four rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use aggregation together with your `WHERE` condition, with no need of a nested query:

```
select avg(dur)
from work
where workdur like '%PB_%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
select avg(dur)
from (select dur  from work where workdur like '%PB_%');
```

**One important thing** you should notice is that in oracle (sql, in general), `_` is a wildcards like `%`, so careful with your `like` because it equal to `like '%PB%'`

So for your case you should change to (and remove nested, according to suggest from @Aleksej)

```
select avg(dur)
from work 
where workdur like '%PB\_%' escape '\';
```

Comment: oh no need to do group

Comment: Why the nested query?

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    id INT
    , dur INT
    , workdur VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #test (id, dur, workdur)
VALUES (1, 64, '/home/public/users/james/PB_3594162_0')
    , (2, 123, '/home/public/users/john/PB_990-94162_0')
    , (3, 13, '/doc/users/jason/PB_0125135')
    , (4, 355, '/doc/users/jason/notPB');

SELECT AVG(CAST(dur AS FLOAT))
FROM #test
WHERE workdur LIKE '%PB\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

I'm casting `workdur` as FLOAT, because then it will give you values even after comma (unless you store it as a FLOAT anyway).

On top of that, `_` is a special symbol in `LIKE` and needs to be escaped if you want to treat it as a underscore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple patterns to search for, grouping does become useful and you can use case:

```
select 
  avg(dur), 
  (case 
    when workdur like '%PB\_%' then 'PB'
    when workdur like 'Other Pattern' then 'Other Pattern'
    else 'Not PB' end
  ) as pb 
from work 
group by pb
```